# Notepad++ source mapping for remote debugging with Xdebug

Tags: php, notepad++, xdebug, remote-debugging

I have some PHP applications on a remote CentOS 6.5 computer. Now I want to debug the applications from within my Windows XP developer machine using Notepad++. Xdebug is configured just fine. **But I can't get the source mapping in Notepad++ to work correctly.**

I always get the error: *Unable to map remote: file:///var/www/html/index.php (ip: 192.168.1.17 idekey: dbgp) fallback to source*

I tried all the different suggestions I found anywhere about this topic. Prepending a *file://* before the remote path, appending slashes or not, trying all variants of paths... The only solution to suppress this message, is checking the DBGp configuration option:

☑ Use SOURCE command for all files and bypass mapping

Then the sources are always obtained directly from the server and i get files like this: *dbgp_file%3a%2f%2f%2fvar%2fwww%2fhtml%2findex.php*. I don't know if that is the right way and if it allows for the same functionality as a fully working mapping.

After searching heavily for this issue, I figured out that there are people who fixed this issue for themself. **But they are always using SAMBA in order to have the sources on the Windows machine.**

I don't really want to use Samba, I would like to have a copy of the PHP sources to which I want to map the debug information.

**So, is it possible to have this mapping without SAMBA?** Or am I doing something else wrong? I feel thankful for all kind of support to this.

Sebastian

Here are my Xdebug settings (/etc/php.d/xdebug.ini):

```
; Enable xdebug extension module
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so

xdebug.auto_trace=On
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

Here is my Notepad++ DBGp configuration:

☐ Bypass all mappings (local windows setup)

Remote Server IP: intranet (mapped to 192.168.1.17 via hosts file)

IDE KEY: dbgp

Remote Path: file:///var/www/html

Local Path: D:\DebugSources

☑ Refresh local context on every step
☑ Refresh global context on every step
☐ Use SOURCE command for all files and bypass mapping
☐ Start with closed socket (firewall conflicts work around)
☐ Break at first line when debugging starts
Maximum depth of elements: 3
Maximum child elements: 15
Maximum variable data: 512

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same issue.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. And since then, I did not investigate this further.

Comment: I actually got mine working with a combination of tactics from the various forums. Here's a screenshot of my settings. (I used trailing slashes at the ends) https://imgur.com/RxmLG0o
I also opened up port 9000 on my client router, and allowed it through with ufw on the server side.